# How do I send a email on jekins for any build failure on the server

Tags: email, jenkins

Our jenkins server has a lot of jobs, is there anyway to configure so that an email is sent when any build breaks? I know how to do it for each job individually, but I'd like to set up a global configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using this https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuration+Slicing+Plugin

There is a way to configure emails for all jobs at once

Answer (score 0):

We use the Email Extension Plugin.
 [image: Email Notification Plug In]

and then configure our SMTP Server in the General Configuration.
[image: SMTP Server in the General Configuration]
Once this is all setup, then add a Post Build event in your Jenkins job to send an email on failure.
[image: Post Build event]

Comment: I want a away to do it without having to edit each build individually (we have 50+ jobs)